# how to create asp button with Materialize template

Tags: html, asp.net, materialize

I am using materialize template, while creating a button in asp.net, so when I create simple html button like follows

```
<div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
     <button class="btn cyan waves-effect waves-light right" type="submit"      name="action">Login</button>                                                    
</div>
```

it is rendered properly but when I create button using asp:button control like follows

```
<div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
     <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" CssClass="btn cyan waves-effect waves-light right" Text="Aniket" />
</div>
```

it is rendered as follows

```
<div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
   <i style="" class="btn cyan waves-effect waves-light right waves-input-wrapper">
   <input name="btn" value="Aniket" id="btn" class="waves-button-input" type="submit"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a link instead of a button :

```
<div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btn" CssClass="btn cyan waves-effect waves-light right" runat="server" Text="Aniket"></asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

That's what I did.
I could even put a `OnClick="Logon_Click"` listener on it !